# Notification mail about high memory usage?

Tags: memory

I received a shocking mail from my WordPress site, don't know what to do,

Can anyone help me out in this

> Subject: [Online MBA] High memory
>   usage notification Sent: Feb 13, 2011
>   11:33 PM
>
> WordPress memory usage exceeded 64 MB
>   WordPress peak memory usage: 114.87 MB
>   Number of database queries: 173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mail seems to come from [the TPC! Memory Usage plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tpc-memory-usage/). The description includes *Send e-mail notification if memory usage reaches threshold setting*, and it seems that is what happened here. Either change your plugins so they use less memory, increase the notification limit, or remove this plugin.

Comment: I am increasing my memory limit through editing php.ini file, and one doubt is this plugin good to have in wordpress?

Comment: @ntechi: The plugin seems to be useful when you are having memory issues, you can use it to pinpoint the problems. Why did you install it?

Comment: I installed this to track the load on server,
I also want to ask, how can I track the files in wordpress which are causing load on memory or server?

Comment: @ntechi: You can't pinpoint memory usage to specific files, but it appears you can set "checkpoints" with this plugin, and it will measure the memory usage at specific points in the execution of the script. But I don't know the details of that plugin, you will have to look at the documentation yourself.